# Blurry distorted text and icons

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, resolution, scaling

So my text and icons look blurry, distorted and It also looks like small top portion of letters are being cut off by like 1 pixel. But the thing is that 20% of right side of the screen seem normal, this issue happened randomly after I opened a game, after closing it I noticed this issue. I tried changing scaling, reinstalling drivers, running safe mode, changing cables, also I have 2 monitors, second one doesn't have this issue. It seems like some kind of display adjustment issue to me and should be fixable. Model of the monitor Asus ROG Strix XG258Q

second monitor(good) - [prnt.sc/SQR9u5Q4HbIF](https://prnt.sc/SQR9u5Q4HbIF) monitor with issue - [prnt.sc/0mCzCWEGJwue](https://prnt.sc/0mCzCWEGJwue) On second screen shot you can clearly see that letters G and F and number 7 are being cut off, also it looks 10 times worse IRL, I don't know why camera couldn't capture it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add a screen shot, by camera, if need be, to show issue.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't very clear what is exactly my issue, I'll attach screen shots.
second monitor(good) - https://prnt.sc/SQR9u5Q4HbIF
monitor with issue - https://prnt.sc/0mCzCWEGJwue
On second screen shot you can cleary see that letters G and F and number 7 are being cut off, also it looks 10 times worse IRL, I don't know why camera couldn't capture it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik didn't tag sorry, comment above

Comment: Try moving the monitor's on-screen menu into the corrupted area, if it can be moved. Is it also affected?

Comment: @DanielB on screen menu can't be moved, it does look like it is also affected, but I hardly ever used it so maybe it always was like that, it looks way worse on deskstop or any app. The monitor i'm currently using that has this issue Asus ROG Strix XG258Q

Comment: @Domen1k, can you switch the monitor cables, to see if perhaps the issue is with a cable, or with output through one port, rather than with the particular monitor?

Comment: You have enough components in your arsenal to solve this yourself through trial and error.  90% of PC hardware troubleshooting is swap X out for Y and see if the problem keeps happening.  Narrow down the cause.. then don't deny the results.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Tried that already didn't help

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The thing is I remember that same thing happened before and I forgot how I fixed it so it is fixable I hope

Comment: If the OSD is affected, it is highly unlikely to be caused by your PC or software running on it. Try the monitor with a different connection (type) and/or PC.

Comment: @DanielB I tried running it through HDMI port instead of DP using my laptop still same issue, but I figured out that the more you increase display scaling the less area of monitor is affected, at 175% scaling there's no more letter cut off or distortion visible at any portion of the screen, but using 175% scaling is kind of unusable